# How to set custom separator between items of ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Is there a way to use custom delegate as a separator between every two consecutive items of `ListView` just like `header` and `footer` properties?

Comment: What is a splitter in ListView and what it can be used for?

Comment: @folibis probably, term "separator" would be more appropriate. Basicly, I want to be able to draw a horizontal line between every two consecutive items.

Comment: I've updated my question description.

Answer (score 4):

A `ListView` can be divided in `sections`, aka groups. The documentation provides a nice example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section-prop).

Basically you define a `Component`, much like you do for `Header` and `Footer`, and set it in the `section.delegate` subproperty. In code:

```
ListView {
        id: view
        [...]

        section.property: "size"                    // <--- the splitting property name
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString    // <--- specify the way section is created (see the provided link)
        section.delegate: sectionDelegate           // <--- your delegate
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was aware of `ListView`'s `section` feature, but haven't think of placing each item in a separate section. Alas, it will draw the separator even before the first item in the list.

Comment: Uhm, I see. Sorry for telling old stuff. :) If you need just a splitter, an approach would be to define a custom bool property, set that as a section criteria and then bind section delegate visibility property to the value of the property itself. Just a naive approach, I know.

Comment: I guess you should make a separator as part of ListView item. Section is more intended to group items.

Comment: @folibis That's what I've ended up with, but this approach is a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Put your item inside a ColumnLayout with a Rectangle like this above:

```cpp
ListView {
    id: list
    clip: true
    model: ...
    spacing: 3
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    delegate: ColumnLayout {
        width: list.width
        spacing: list.spacing

        MyItemDelegate {
            ...
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "#999999"
            Layout.preferredHeight: 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            visible: (index !== (list.count - 1))
        }
    }
}
```

That way the separator will show only between itens, not on last item.
And you can continue to use the sections for which they were created.

Answer (score 0):

I just added:

```
Text {
    text: "____________________________________________"
    color: "black"
}
```

To the end of my Item.